# Inserting fake data in ArcGIS database automatically?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I am making a demo database for property search web app. I want to insert fake names (Ethiopian names), geographical location, and other user information.

How can I populate the fields with fake data in ArcGIS 10.3 automatically?

I know this is possible in python Faker library.

Or from watching smart TV don't they collect humongous data?

Comment: I would imagine that an InsertCursor and the Python's random would play a part in any code snippet that you test and present.

Comment: Generating fake data, especially fake textual data is far more difficult than loading real data.  ArcGIS provides plenty of tools for the latter, but not much for the former.

Comment: The solution I came up with was three_bed_room_winners.pdf from City of Addis Ababa condominium winners, Amharic names.